# Unicode support in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unicode

The problem I have is I wish to support unicode within my project (mvc project).

Where by a user can post a comment using characaters such as ペ without this becoming ????.

Any information that can be shared on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it? Obviously your backing store has to be Unicode aware too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what is basically a Character Set and Encoding.

A character set defines a set of textual and graphic symbols, each of which is mapped to a set of non negative integers.  For example, when the database stores the letter A, it actually stores a numeric code that is interpreted by software as the letter ”A”, the numeric code is called code point or encoded value.

Character encoding is a process of assigning code point to a character; it defines a rule for representing and storing a character in a character set.

Also You need to know what collation is,  which is just a bit patterns that represent every character and some rules which are applied on characters being stored and compared, in case you are storing the same in your database.

In a Nutshell you need to change your page charset to charset="UTF-8" for all your web pages, and do the same activity on your database.